# Laravel compare between inserted column and another in the same row

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a table of stores, I calculated distances between these stores locations and customer location, I want to compare if the distance is greater than the store coverage then don't show this store in the list
I know that can use havingRaw but if Im using \DB::table('stores') but in my case I added the column of distances after I get all stores, for now I'm using this in the blade and working fine but wondered if can do it in the controller

```
      @if($item->store_coverage >= $item->distance)

return $stores->where('distance','>',0 )->where('distance <= store_coverage')->sortBy('distance');
```

Hope you get what I need

thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "do it in the controller"? Why do you need such logic in a controller? Put it into a proper service, such that you can reuse and test it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use collections filter helper

```
$stores->filter(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->store_coverage >= $item->distance;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to breakup the where statement into its arguments and were calling sortBy on the query object, not the results collection.

```
$stores->where('distance', '>', 0)
       ->where('distance', '<=', 'store_coverage')
       ->get()
       ->sortBy('distance');
```

Comment: this is not correct, I told you I have the stores after I added get then I compared these stores with their locations... etc so to add get will cause error Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in

Comment: What is the $stores variable?